# How to set m_ prefix for private fields via .editorconfig for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, editorconfig

I want to configure .editorconfig so it uses "m_" prefix for all private fields in C#/.NET. Can't find a setting that works.

The rule should be supported in the current Visual Studio 2017. Preferably by ReSharper as well.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like that's [not supported](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties)

Comment: Note that what you want goes against the [field names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-fields) rule in the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/).

Comment: Doesn't matter in my case. I'd like to move a large existing code base to .editorconfig instead of resharper rules and keep the most prominent conventions as they are. So you can basically open the code with and without resharper installed and use the same rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_have_prefix.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_have_prefix.symbols  = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_should_have_prefix.style    = private_prefix_style

dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds   = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.required_modifiers = private

dotnet_naming_style.private_prefix_style.required_prefix = m_
dotnet_naming_style.private_prefix_style.capitalization = camel_case
```